# How to create radar chart in Android app using Adobe Flex 4.6

Tags: android, apache-flex

A solution that works both on Android mobile application using Adobe Flex and desktop application using Adobe AIR is preferred. I guess this should be a basic feature, without extended support from third party library. But don't have a clue after searching on Internet.

The Kap Lab components (found on Adobe's [Flex / Extend : Related products](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/extend.html) page) seem not working on Android mobile device. This is the error message I received when running it on Android mobile device:

```
1046 : Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [mx.controls.treeClasses]::ITreeDataDescriptor.
```

My desktop development environment is:

> (1) Adobe Flash Builder 4.7
>
> (2) Adobe Flex SDK 4.6
>
> (3) ActionScript 3.0

Any hint is appreciated :D

Comment: In your project references, make sure you have mx.swc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628567/migrating-from-flex-3-6-to-4-6/14629726#14629726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex mobile sdk is optimized and compressed for mobile, so it misses some classes used by Kep Lab, or even the Flex charts. You should write the charts from bottom up. Good news, if it will work on mobile, it will work on desktop as well. You can of course try to import the missing classes from the open source sdk, but it would be a big mess, and it was not a coincidence tat they've left them out.

Answer (score 1):

In your project references, make sure you have mx.swc. The mobile profile does not include the mx components by default. this needs to be added separately. You can do so by going into Flex Build Path, Library Path, clicking on add SWC and choosing mx.swc from your sdk frameworks folder.

See [migrating from Flex 3.6 to 4.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14628567/migrating-from-flex-3-6-to-4-6/14629726#14629726)