# Flex 3.6 to 4.6/4.9 Migration issue

Tags: apache-flex, migration

I am getting the following error while migrating to version 4.6/4.9. Same thing works fine in flex version 3.6.

Can somebody please help me to resolve it?

**4.6 Error**

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "/" to flash.display.DisplayObject.
                at mx.charts.chartClasses::ChartBase/ttp://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::addElements()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\charts\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\ChartBase.as:4302]
                at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/ttp://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::updateSeries()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\charts\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\CartesianChart.as:1041]
                at mx.charts.chartClasses::ChartBase/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\charts\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\ChartBase.as:1918]
                at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/commitProperties()[**E:\dev\4.y**\frameworks\projects\charts\src\mx\charts\chartClasses\CartesianChart.as:934]
                at mx.core::****UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8219****]
                at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
                at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:783]
                at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

**4.9 Error**

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "/" to flash.display.DisplayObject. 
        at mx.charts.chartClasses::ChartBase/ttp://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::addElements()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/charts/src/mx/charts/chartClasses/ChartBase.as:4310] 
        at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/ttp://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::updateSeries()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/charts/src/mx/charts/chartClasses/CartesianChart.as:1050] 
        at mx.charts.chartClasses::ChartBase/commitProperties()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/**ApacheFlexSDK**/frameworks/projects/charts/src/mx/charts/chartClasses/ChartBase.as:1926] 
        at mx.charts.chartClasses::CartesianChart/commitProperties()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/charts/src/mx/charts/chartClasses/CartesianChart.as:943] 
        at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/core/UIComponent.as:8227] 
        at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/LayoutManager.as:605] 
        at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/LayoutManager.as:791] 
        at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlexSDK/frameworks/projects/framework/src/mx/managers/LayoutManager.as:1188]
```

Comment: Migrated Namespace used at top is as follows: <mx:VBox xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:fx="ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"; xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%" preinitialize="initHandler();" verticalGap="0" xmlns:containers="net.minmax.containers.*">

Comment: <mx:VBox id="returnChart" height="100%" width="100%"> <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" showDataTips="true" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{chartProvider}" styleName="testChart" horizontalAxis="{dAxis}"> <mx:verticalAxis> <mx:LinearAxis id="v2" title="Test ($100)" interval="50"/> </mx:verticalAxis> <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers> <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{dAxis}" labelRotation="45" placement="bottom"/> </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers><mx:verticalAxisRenderers> <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left" axis="{v2}" verticalAxisTitleAlignment="vertical"/> </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
           <mx:series>

Comment: jigar, please edit your question with additional code.  No one wants to bother trying to parse code from comment formatting!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a String "/" in a CartesianChart somewhere in your code where it expects a DisplayObject

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "/" to flash.display.DisplayObject.
```

Comment: Also, we are using ColumnChart however it is showing exception related to CartesianChart.

Comment: Can you show the column chart code? ColumnChart extends CartesianChart

Comment: <mx:VBox id="returnChart" height="100%" width="100%">
    <mx:ColumnChart id="myChart" showDataTips="true" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{chartProvider}"
     styleName="testChart" horizontalAxis="{dAxis}">
           <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="v2" title="Test ($100)" interval="50"/>
           </mx:verticalAxis>
           <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
               <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{dAxis}" labelRotation="45" placement="bottom"/>
           </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers><mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
               <mx:AxisRenderer placement="left"

Comment: Migrated Namespace used at top is as follows:

<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%" preinitialize="initHandler();" 
 verticalGap="0" xmlns:containers="net.minmax.containers.*">

Comment: Please add it to your question